# 9Patch alternative in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, android-layout, flutter-layout, nine-patch

How do I implement a design as show below?

[image: screenshot]

The image shows a play button with text. I won't be creating it as a container with gradient of some sort.
This leaves me with 2 options

1. Define 2 growable rectangles before and after the text, which can be used to scale with width of the image.
2. Define 1 growable rectangle for **image without text** and then somehow place the text within the image and also allow the button to have scalable size.

But how do I do any of that without 9patch of native android?

EDIT:

```
Container(
//        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => print('onPressed'),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: Ink.image(
            image: FileImage(File('btn_default_normal.9.png')),
            centerSlice: Rect.fromLTWH(18 - 1.0, 36 - 1.0, 2, 2),
            child: Text(
              'press me',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

---

How to set the width? Uncommenting the width gives me
[image: screenshot]

which means the button is taking half the screen width but not expanding.

Comment: If you get your answer, please share it with me thanks

Comment: @abbasjafary just follow the question or bookmark it.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/centerSlice.html and https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/DecorationImage/centerSlice.html

Comment: @pskink I tried using it but the image is pixelated. A code sample would really help. I came across this page https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16098 but no help.

Comment: `child: FlatButton(
  onPressed: () => print('onPressed'),
  child: Ink.image(
    image: FileImage(File('btn_default_normal.9.png')),
    centerSlice: Rect.fromLTWH(18, 36, 2, 2),
    child: Center(child: Text('press me', textScaleFactor: 2)),
  ),
),`

Comment: sample image: [btn_default_normal.9.png](https://pasteboard.co/Jpamcgo.png)

Comment: trying it out. not pixelated. how do i scale it from outside? currently scaling it using padding on the text which seems to work fine.

Comment: `"how do i scale it from outside"` - i have no idea what you mean

Comment: Something like `Container(width:x,height:y,child: YourWidget()),` without padding the text. Currently I am doing `YourWidget(child:Padding(padding:p,child:Text("some text")));` which works fine.

Comment: `Container(width:..., height:...)` works just fine: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints `^F Example 3`

Comment: I have added some code and my result. Please take a look.

Comment: @pskink Okay, i got it working. Thanks for your help. Is there way to have multiple expanding regions within the image?

Comment: no, only one slice is allowed

Comment: okay, thanks again.